# Python not saving variable values when they are changed inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I saved my variables at the start of my program and allow the functions to access them I believe but when they run the value is not saved when the function repeats.

```py
P1_score = 0
P2_score = 0
round_number = 0

def dice_rolling():
    # P1D1 means player ones dice one value and so on with P1D2
    import random
    # player ones turn
    print("player ones turn")
    P1D1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    print("your number is ", P1D1)
    P1D2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    print("your second number is", P1D2)
    # player twos turn
    print("player twos turn")
    P2D1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    print("your number is", P2D1)
    P2D2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    print("your second number is", P2D2)
    score_calculation(P1D1, P1D2, P2D1, P2D2,P1_score,P2_score,round_number)


def score_calculation(P1D1, P1D2, P2D1, P2D2,P1_score,P2_score,round_number):
    import random
    
    round_number = round_number + 1
    # player 1 score calculation
    total_P1 = P1D1 + P1D2
    P1_score = P1_score + total_P1
    if total_P1 % 2 == 0:
        P1_score = P1_score + 10
    else:
        P1_score = P1_score + 5
    if P1D1 == P1D2:
        P1D3 = random.randint(1, 6)
        P1_score = P1_score + P1D3

    # player 2 score calculation
    total_P2 = P2D1 + P2D2
    P2_score = P2_score + total_P2
    if total_P2 % 2 == 0:
        P2_score = P2_score + 10
    else:
        P2_score = P2_score + 5
    if P2D1 == P2D2:
        P2D3 = random.randint(1, 6)
        P2_score = P2_score + P2D3
    print("player ones score at the end of round", round_number, "is", P1_score)
    print("player twos score at the end of round",round_number,"is",P2_score)

    
for x in range(0,5):
    dice_rolling()
```

Any help would be appreciated and if someone could give a simple explanation as to what I'm doing wrong and what to fix would be great.

Comment: local variables inside a function do not reflect changes in outer scopes. Please consider reading [the scope docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example). If you want to access a global variable within a function, use the [`global`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python) keyword.

Comment: will have a read thank you

Comment: Also, please explain *which* variables you think are not reflecting changes as well as how you expect the variables to behave. Your question is very unclear right now.

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: how would i turn these into locals by any chance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python can read from global variables inside a function, but can't assign them without some extra work. In general, when you want to use a global variable, it's a good idea to make it explicit by using the `global` keyword in your function:

```
my_global_var = 0

def some_function():
    global my_gobal_var
    
    my_global_var = 10

print(my_global_var) # it prints 10

somefunction() # modifies the global var

print(my_global_var) # now it prints 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are defined and used locally. Consider this example.

```
x = 1 #initial value
def test(x):
    print(x) #print what you got
    x += 1
    print(x) #print updated value

print(x) #Actual printouts here
test(x)
print(x)
```

This results in :

```
1 
1 #value when entering the function
2 #Value changed by function
1 #value outside the function did not change
```

If you want the variables to be maintained in functions, consider using class variables or global variables. (I recommend avoiding globals as you get to more complex problems)

Global example:

```
global x
x = 1
def test():
    global x
    x+=1
print(x)
test()
print(x)
test()
print(x)
```

Results in :

```
1
2
3
```

Finally class variables:

```
class test_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1 #variables defined like this are class variables
    def test(self):
        self.x += 1 #Advantages of class variables is that you can defined them in the __init__ function
    def running(self):
        print(self.x) # And you can access it from multiple functions without using globals and much more too. 
        self.test()
        print(self.x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tclass = test_class()
    tclass.running()
```